# Missing data from indy TCPServer. Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver

I have an application that uses TIdTCPServer. I send null terminated messages to the server (Delphi XE2, Indy package which ships with it) sucessfully as null terminated strings.
The OnExecute procedure is as follows:

```
procedure TSimpleSslServerForm.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  RxBufStr: string;
begin
  with AContext.Connection.IOHandler do
  begin
   if not InputBufferIsEmpty then
     begin
       RxBufStr := InputBufferAsString;
       Display(RXBufStr);
       lbl_EventsReceived.Caption := IntToStr(StrToInt(lbl_EventsReceived.Caption) + 1);
     end;
   end;
end;
```

My issue is that if i send alot of messages, if i do not put a 200 ms delay between messages then i loose data.

Without added delay:
I either loose data completely (13 messages received from 107 sent) and/ot the data is incorrect:
<38>Jul 10 09:37:39 cilad71 QJRN: ope=JOB WAS CHANGED   date=10/07/15   time=07:59:26   sys=CILAD71 user=GCOX   job=QZSOSIGN    jobn=   ipadr=192.168.5.121 pgm=QZSOSIGN    pgmlib=QSYS  date=07/10/15  time=07:59:26   user=GCOX   action=PROFILE CHANGED  jobname=QZSOSIGN    jobnumber=189191    jobusername=QUSER   jobd=QZBSJOBD   ipaddress=192.168.5.121%

**07/10/15  time=08:01:25   user=GCOX   action=PROFILE CHANGED  jobname=QZSOSIGN    jobnumber=189191    jobusername=QUSER   jobd=QZBSJOBD   ipaddress=192.168.5.121%**

<38>Jul 10 09:37:39 cilad71 QJRN: ope=JOB WAS CHANGED   date=10/07/15   time=08:01:35   sys=CILAD71 user=GCOX   job=QPADEV000D  jobn=   ipadr=192.168.5.121 pgm=QWTPIIPP    pgmlib=QSYS  date=07/10/15  time=08:01:35   user=GCOX   action=START    jobname=QPADEV000D  jobnumber=189401    jobusername=GCOX    jobd=QDFTJOBD   ipaddress=192.168.5.121%

The event in bold is missing data.

I see the same behaviour with the TIdUDPServer component also. The only difference i see is that for UDP the required delay to receive all the data correctly is 100 ms, whereas for the TCP server a delay of less than 200 ms between messages always results in data loss.
For UDP when sending to a Windows Event service so the event appears in the corresponding Windows journal no delay is required and I see all the events correctly.

Thanks, 
Geoff Cox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TIdTCPServer` code you have shown is NOT reading null-terminated messages from the socket.  It is simply reading whatever raw data *happens* to be present on the socket at that particular moment.  There might be no messages at that moment, or there might be a full message, or there might be partial pieces of multiple messages.  This is just how TCP works.

If your messages are truly null-terminated, you need to read them as such, by waiting for the null terminator to arrive and then process whatever precedes it.  For example, you can use the `TIdIOHandler.ReadLn()` or `TIdIOHandler.WaitFor()` method for that purpose:

```
procedure TSimpleSslServerForm.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  RxBufStr: string;
begin
  RxBufStr := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn(#0);
  ...
end;
```

```
procedure TSimpleSslServerForm.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  RxBufStr: string;
begin
  RxBufStr := AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WaitFor(#0);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy.
The WaitFor(#0) method gives the correct result.